# Do C++ and Python write to disk differently?

Tags: python, c++, optimization, filesystems

So, a few years ago I wrote a program in Python that writes the English names of a sequential list of numbers to a file (one, two, three, etc.).  I have been working on getting a C++ version working off and on for the last month (personal project), and I think I have it running pretty well.  One problem: it's **five times slower** than the Python version.  I've tried switching string concatenation methods ( `<<` vs `operator+` vs `operator+=` vs `.append()`), using `fprinf()` instead of `ofstream`, pre-allocating the string size (`.reserve()`), and a lot of other things I can't remember, but I seemed to have run into a wall.  Then I noticed that the C++ writing speed seems to max out around 70MB/s, whereas the Python version writes at around 350MB/s.  The drive I am using is a 5400rpm disk (CrystalDiskMark gives a sequential write speed of 60-90 MB/s), so the C++ write speeds are believable, but the Python?

**TL;DR**: Python seems to be writing five times faster than possible, (near to the read speeds!) of the disk.

I've included the programs below, in case I am missing something obvious (plausible). "Benchmarking" involved running each program for the numbers 1-1,000,000, resulting in a file of 50,824KB.  ~50s for C++, ~8.5s for Python.

## Python:

```
##Code in Python version 2.7.5 for generating a file with the English names of a set range of numbers.
while 1:
    s=input("Starting_Value:")
    f=input("Ending_Value:")
    filename=raw_input("Desired Name of File:")   

    ##dictionary
    one=["","one","two","three","four","five","six","seven","eight","nine","error_one"]
    one2=["","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine","error_one2"]
    teen=["ten","eleven","twelve","thirteen","fourteen","fifteen","sixteen","seventeen","eighteen","nineteen","error_teen"]
    ten=["","twenty","thirty","fourty","fifty","sixty","seventy","eighty","ninety","error_ten"]

    ##Functions
    def translate(n): ##handles '' to 999
        work=[]
        if n>=100:
            work.append(one[int(n/100)]+" hundred ")
            n=n-(100*int(n/100))
            if n>=10:
                if n>=20:
                    work.append(ten[int(n/10)-1]+one2[n-(10*int(n/10))]+" ")
                else:
                    work.append(teen[n%10]+" ")
            elif n>=1:
                work.append(one[n]+ " ")
        elif n>=10:
            if n>=20:
                work.append(ten[int(n/10)-1]+one2[n-(10*int(n/10))]+" ")
            else:
                work.append(teen[n%10]+" ")
        elif n>=1:
            work.append(str(one[n])+" ")
        end1=', '.join(work)
        end1=end1.replace(", ","")
        return end1

    def english(m): ##handles billions, hundred millions, millions, hundred thousands, thousands
        work2=[]
        if m>=1000000000:
            work2.append(str(translate(int(m/1000000000)))+"billion ")
        elif m>=1000000:
            work2.append(str(translate(int(m/1000000)))+"million "+str(translate(int(m-(1000000*int(m/1000000)))/1000))+"thousand "+str(translate(m-(1000*int(m/1000)))))
            if ((int(m/1000)%1000)==0):
                end3=str(', '.join(work2))
                end4=end3.replace("thousand ", "")
                work2[:]=[]
                work2=[str(end4)]
            else:
                end3=str()
        elif m>=1000:
            work2.append(str(translate(int(m/1000)))+"thousand "+str(translate(m%1000)))
        elif m>=1:
            work2.append(translate(m))
        end2=str(', '.join(work2))
        end2=end2[:-1]
        return end2
    ##Main Program - Iterator
    file = open(str(filename), "a")
    for i in range(f-s+1):
        file.write(str(english(s))+", ")
        s = s + 1
    file.close()
    a = raw_input("Close window to EXIT, or press ENTER to generate another file")
```

## C++

```
//Generates a file of sequential numbers in English

//libraries
#include <iostream> //for output to terminal
#include <fstream>  //for output to file
#include <string>   //for handling strings

using namespace std;        //yes

ofstream fout;              //for convenience with 'cout'

//function prototypes
string thousands(int n);    //translates 1 to 999
string millions(int m);     //translates the hundred thousands, millions, 
hundred millions
int lint(int j, int k);     //outputs the digits of a number greater than the kth place i.e. lint(123456, 1000) = 123

//variables
int shi = 0;                //starting value
int kut = 1;                //ending value
int i = 0;                  //iterator
string fname = "";          //filename
string buffern = "";        //buffer for thousands
string bufferm = "";        //buffer for millions
string bufferf = "";        //first digit buffer

//dictionary
char one[10][7] = { ""," one"," two"," three"," four"," five"," six"," seven"," eight"," nine" };
char one2[10][7] = { "","-one","-two","-three","-four","-five","-six","-seven","-eight","-nine" };
char teen[10][11] = { " ten"," eleven"," twelve"," thirteen"," fourteen"," fifteen"," sixteen"," seventeen"," eighteen"," nineteen" };
char ten[10][9] = { "",""," twenty"," thirty"," fourty"," fifty"," sixty"," seventy"," eighty"," ninety" };

//main function
int main()
{
    while (1)
    {
        //get user input
        cout << " Starting Number: ";
        cin >> shi;
        cout << " Ending Number: ";
        cin >> kut;
        while (fout.is_open() != 1)
        {
            cout << " Desired Filename: ";
            cin >> fname;
            fname.append(".txt");
            fout.open(fname);
            if (fout.is_open() != 1)
                cout << "\n   Invalid file name.  Please try again.\n";
        }

        //translate and write to file 
        if (shi == 0) {                 //handles starting at zero
            fout << "zero,";
            shi = 1;
        }
        else                            //handles spacing for next word
        {
            bufferf = millions(shi);
            bufferf.erase(0, 1);
            bufferf += ",";
            fout << bufferf;
            shi++;
        }
        for (i = shi; i < (kut); ++i)   //Main Iterator
        {
            fout << millions(i) << ",";
        }
        fout << millions(kut) << ".";   //handles last word
        fout.close();

        //display confirmation and prompt to exit/continue
        cout << "\n Complete\n";
        cin.get();
        cin.ignore();
        cout << endl;
    }
}

//function definitions
string thousands(int n)     //writes '' to 999
{
    buffern = ""; 
    buffern.reserve(30);
    if (n >= 100) {                     //write hundreds place
        buffern += one[lint(n, 100)];
        buffern += " hundred";
        n = n % 100;
        if (n >= 10) {                  //write tens place
            if (n >= 20) {
                buffern += ten[lint(n, 10)];
                buffern += one2[n % 10];
            }
            else {                      //deal with 'teens'
                buffern += teen[n % 10];
            }
        }
        else if (n >= 1) {              //write ones place
            buffern += one[n % 10];
        }
    }
    else if (n >= 10) {                 //write tens place
        if (n >= 20) {
            buffern += ten[lint(n, 10)];
            buffern += one2[n % 10];
        }
        else {                          //deal with 'teens'
            buffern += teen[n % 10];
        }
    }
    else if (n >= 1) {                  //write ones place
        buffern += one[n];
    }
    return buffern;
}

string millions(int m)
{
    bufferm = "";
    bufferm.reserve(100);
    if (m >= 1000000)
    {
        if (int(m / 1000) % 1000 == 0) {                //if xxx,000,xxx
            bufferm += thousands(lint(m, 1000000));
            bufferm += " million";
            bufferm += thousands(m % 1000);
        }
        else {
            bufferm += thousands(lint(m, 1000000));     //millions
            bufferm += " million";
            bufferm += thousands(lint(m, 1000) % 1000); //hundred thousands
            bufferm += " thousand";
            bufferm += thousands(m % 1000);             //thousands
        }
    }
    else if (m >= 1000) {
        bufferm += thousands(lint(m, 1000));            //hundred thousands
        bufferm += " thousand";
        bufferm += thousands(m % 1000);                 //thousands
    }
    else if (m >= 1) {
        bufferm += thousands(m);                        //thousands
    }
    return bufferm;
}

int lint(int j, int k)
{
    return ((j - (j % k)) / k);
}
```

I would appreciate any insights as to why the programs are running at different speeds, how the Python is writing so fast, or suggestions on speeding up the c++ code.

**Edit**: @VTT was right, not all of the C++ code was there.  Added.

Comment: Both will utilize the same I/O API provided by operating system. So performance difference may emerge only from that fancy word building code. Also usual question: did you enable optimizations when compiling c++ code? And c++ implementation seems to be incomplete, for example there is no `millions` function.

Comment: Unrelated. Lot of global variables in that C++ code. I'm betting you don't need any of them.

Comment: More useful, Your development environment may come with a profiling software. Run it and see what's eating up all of your time.

Comment: @VTT Okay, optimization wasn't enabled... C++ now runs at basically the same speed as Python.  Thanks!  Still not sure why it can write so fast... Could this be due to the burst speed just being much faster than CrystalDisk measures it?

Comment: @IronEagle: Operating systems (and even libraries) do caching/buffering. Since you are not flushing/syncing the changes to the disk, you are not really waiting/measuring the time it takes to actually write the data to the disk -- that is why you see speeds faster than your disk.

Comment: @Acorn: not counting that the transfers can occur under DMA.